# Multiple Volley request in a single Activity

Tags: android, android-volley

I have implemented Volley request in this `Activity`. The request is sent twice  whenever this `comment()` method is called. This method is called `onClickListner` of `Button` where `Activity` is launched when a `Button` is clicked on card which is placed in `Fragment`.

```
private void comment1(String id) {
    String url = "http://52.66.103.123:8000/comment/" + GlobalUtilityClass.getValueOnUserPrefernces(getContext(), "my_id") + "/" + id;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("comentfriend", response);
                   // Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("responsefriend_error", error.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
            arguments.put("commentName", edittext1);
            return arguments;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            6000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
}
```